# Why Android is forcing using screenOrientation fullSensor?

Tags: android, android-manifest, screen-orientation

Why Android Studio 3.6.2 is forcing me to use `fullSensor` `screenOrientation`?

I noticed that it can be suppressed using `tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"`, but why is it there in the first place? 
Will anything broke if suppress it?

---

[image: Android Manifest]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that on chrome devices the landscape orientation may look buggy. So the solution that I found is to use `fullSensor` in the manifest and manually apply orientation in the code if not running on Chrome devices.

```
<manifest ...>
   <application ...>
   ...
      <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"/>
   ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```

And then in the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_PC)){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```